# C endianness ( Store python object without swapping)

Tags: c, python-2.7

I want  to write the  hexadecimal string that is passed from python  as  it is  on disk in C .

My problem is that  the values are getting stored  in little endian and the values are  swapped .

Example  :

if I pass a PyObject  i.e “abcdef12345123”  it should be written on disk the given offset as it is  i.e. “abcdef12345123”

Here is the sample code and  result with this code.

## sample code

```
static PyObject *
py_corrupt_disk_object(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{

        int size, optype, fixcrc;
        long offset;
        PyObject *baddr;
        char *op_value = NULL;

        if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,"Oliisi", &baddr, &offset, &size, &optype,
            &op_value,&fixcrc))
                Py_RETURN_NONE;

        d_locn_t locn = {};
        locn.idx.devid  = ((struct py_ifs_baddr*)baddr)->baddr.devid;
        locn.idx.drive  = ((struct py_ifs_baddr*)baddr)->baddr.drive;
        locn.idx.subidx = ((struct py_ifs_baddr*)baddr)->baddr._subblk;
        locn.idx.index  = ((struct py_ifs_baddr*)baddr)->baddr._block;

        d_print("Printing args in py_corrupt_disk_object: \n");
        d_print("offset %lu \n",offset);
        d_print("fixcrc %d \n",fixcrc);
        d_print("size %d \n",size);
        d_print("optype %d \n",optype);
        d_print("op_value %s \n",op_value);


        d_cpr_write(&locn, offset, size, optype, op_value, fixcrc);
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
}


PyObject*
d_cpr_write(d_locn_t *locn, int offset, int size, int optype, char *op_value, int fixcrc)
{

        cpr_obj* obj = NULL;
        struct po_typeinfo *tinfo = NULL;
        int obj_size = 0;
        d_print("The Values inside d_cpr_write():\n");
        d_print("offset %d \n",offset);
        d_print("fixcrc %d \n",fixcrc);
        d_print("size %d \n",size);
        d_print("optype %d \n",optype);
        d_print("op_value %s \n",op_value);


        if (locn->idx.subidx & BADDR_SIZE_512) {
                obj_size = BUFFER_512;
                tinfo = find_object('i');
                if (locn_iaddr_to_linsnap(locn) != d_OK) {
                        d_log(d_ERR, "lin snap conversion failed\n");
                        Py_RETURN_NONE;
                }
                locn->flags |= DLFLAG_HASXIADDRHINT;
                locn->xiaddrhint = d_index_to_baddr(locn->idx);
        } else {
                obj_size = BUFFER_8192;
                tinfo = find_object('b');
        }

        if (tinfo == NULL) {
                d_log(d_ERR, "Only Object i or b supported\n");
                Py_RETURN_NONE;
        }

        obj = alloc_objarg();

        // create cpr object
        obj->tinfo = tinfo;
        obj->locn = *locn;

        unsigned char *buff = NULL;
        if (!(buff = alloca(obj_size))) {
                d_log(d_ERR, "buffer allocation failed\n");
                Py_RETURN_NONE;
        }

        int index, xfered, bit_offset;

        if ((xfered = (*obj->tinfo->read)(&obj->locn, buff, obj_size)) < 0) {
                d_log(d_ERR, "read failed %d\n", xfered);
                Py_RETURN_NONE;
        }

        if (obj->tinfo->insane != NULL) {
                if ((*obj->tinfo->insane)(&obj->locn, buff, obj_size, 0) < 0) {
                        d_log(d_ERR, "%c object sanity check failed\n",
                            obj->tinfo->type);
                        Py_RETURN_NONE;
                }
        }

       d_print("Entering optype\n");
        if (optype == 2) { //overwrite
                unsigned long opval = strtol(op_value, NULL, 16);
                d_print("after rev =%ld ", opval);
                memcpy(&buff[offset], &opval, sizeof(opval));

         }//End of overwrite
        if (fixcrc)
                obj->locn.flags |= DLFLAG_WRITE_CRC;

        if (!obj->tinfo->write) {
                d_log(d_ERR, "no write function supported\n");
                Py_RETURN_NONE;
        }

        if ((xfered = (*obj->tinfo->write)(&obj->locn, buff, obj_size)) < 0) {
                d_log(d_ERR, "write failed %d\n", xfered);
                Py_RETURN_NONE;
        }

        Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

## Result/output:

```
./python inject_failures.py --optype=add --fixcrc=1 --object=baddr  --baddr=2,3,773463552:512  --offset=16 --mirror=1  --op_value='abcdef12345123' --size=8

> /usr/local_qa/bin/isi_corrupt.py(848)main()

-> if 'add' in options.optype and options.op_value is None:
(Pdb) c

> /usr/local_qa/bin/ inject_failures.py (185)corrupt_diskobject()

-> logging.info("Corrupting disk object %s at %s", obj_type, disk_object)
(Pdb) c
```

Printing args in py_corrupt_disk_object:

offset 16

fixcrc 1

size 8

optype 2

op_value abcdef12345123

The Values inside d_cpr_write():

offset 16

fixcrc 1

size 8

optype 2

op_value abcdef12345123

Entering optype

after rev =48358647703818531

## Problem:

I can see that data is not written correctly ( if I examine using hexdump )

Before:

00000010  e0 01 04 00 01 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|

After :

00000010  23 51 34 12 ef cd ab 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |#Q4.............|  ==>  23513412 efcdab00

## C- Question :

1. Is there a way that I can  stop this translation  and write the values as it in C , from the output looks like we are swapping the  bytes and then writing to disk  in little endian order ?.  I am doing a memcpy() may be there is something else simpler that can help us write the data without swapping  ?
2. The op_value is always 14 digits or 7 bytes. How do I  copy the 7 bytes as it is on disk . (I am new to C so kindly consider this while providing suggestion)

## Python Question

1. Is there something that I can take care in python layer to avoid this swap  or any  other suggestion on how to fix this (I am on Python 2.7 and Linux).

Answer (score 1):

What happens is simple: you get a string and you write a long:

```
unsigned long opval = strtol(op_value, NULL, 16);
```

In a long, the bytes are swapped; in a string they are not. So write a string and everyting is OK.

---

So you want a long, which is stored with the bytes reversed and which is correct, to be stored with the bytes non-reversed? Question would be why, because now no program can read the long back again, but alas, the code to do that is:

```
if (optype == 2) {
    unsigned long opval = strtol(op_value, NULL, 16);
    char *longval, *bufp;
    longval= (char *)&opval;
    bufp= buff;
    for (int i=sizeof(long)-1; i>=0; i--)
        *bufp++ = *(longval+i);
 }
```

Comment: `if (optype == 2) { //overwrite                
                memcpy(&buff[offset], &op_value, sizeof(op_value));
            }//End of overwrite `

@Paul Ogilvie ,  I changed the code as above but I am getting  the values in some other format


**Result:**

_Input : abcdef12345123_

_Output: cc fc 8e 11 08 00 00 00_ //  its now in different format

Comment: @ Paul Ogilvie   I tired your suggestion as follows ,
       if (optype == 2) { //overwrite
                memcpy(&buff[offset], op_value, strlen(op_value)); // Added the new suggestion
                d_print("buff_check %s \n", &buff[offset]);
             }//End of overwrite
No Luck  , I can see that  the buff values getting printed correctly but they get are not getting stored correctly .                                             *00000010  61 62 63 64 65 66 31 32  33 34 35 31 32 33 00 00 * --> (each character is getting converted to its hex value  and getting stored)

Comment: Debugger o/p (Pdb) 
`Printing args in py_corrupt_disk_object:
offset 1`
fixcrc 1
size 14
optype 2
op_value abcdef12345123
The Values inside dda_cpr_write():
offset 16
fixcrc 1
size 14
optype 2
op_value abcdef12345123
Entering optype
buff_check abcdef12345123`

Comment: I already had the hexavalues  i.e abcdef1234567 .  I want to write them as it is and not as  61 62 63 64 65 66 31 32 33 34 35 31 32 33 00   with ' earlier code  'unsigned long opval = strtol(op_value, NULL, 16); ` they were correct expect they were getting swapped

Comment: Sorry but the values are not getting stored correctly on examination

1. 00000010  dd 01 04 00 01 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 *original *

#2. 00000010  61 62 63 64 65 66 31 32  33 34 35 31 32 33 00 00  *with code change  suggested , each character is getting converted to its hex value  and getting stored*

3. 00000010  ab cd ef 12 34  12 30  00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  -- *Expected is to store them as it is *

Comment: What you want sounds stupid, but I added the code to do that.

Comment: It is only after memcpy the values are getting stored correctly but swapped in little endian fashion. 
        `if (optype == 2) { //overwrite
                unsigned long opval = strtol(op_value, NULL, 16); //  if op_value entered by using was  abcdef1234512310
                memcpy(&buff[offset], &opval, sizeof(opval)); // after this statement they are getting stored  in little endian i.e 10 23 51 34 12 ef cd ab ( each byte has 2 hex numbers)
               }'
May be what I need is  (1) a have a loop that can  convert  10 23 51 34 12 ef cd ab   -->  ab cd ef 12 34 51 23 10

Comment: or   (2) or some other logic in C that will help me retain ab cd ef 12 34 51 23 10  --> ab cd ef 12 34 51 23 10 

@Paul Ogilvie  : Really appreciate your help in  answering my questions and Apologies, I think I should have been more clearer